# EF Core - Unique constraint including navigation property not detected in migration

Tags: c#, entity-framework-migrations, ef-core-2.2

I am trying to apply a unique composite constraint, one of the parts of the constraint is a foreign key. The only way I can seem to make it work is to explicitly defined the foreign key in my domain class, which I want to avoid. Is this possible?

The problem and the workaround applies to both `HasAlternateKey` and `HasIndex`. The solution builds fine, but the constraint is ignored when creating a migration until the shadow property is turned into a real property in the domain class.

This does NOT work (migration ignores this):

```
entity.HasAlternateKey(e => new { e.Header.Id, e.Version, e.StartDate });
```

This does work AFTER turning shadow property HeaderID into a real one:

```
entity.HasAlternateKey(e => new { e.HeaderId, e.Version, e.StartDate });
entity.HasOne(e => e.Header).WithMany().HasForeignKey(f => f.HeaderId);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Fluent API do not support nested property expressions like `e.Header.Id`.

As usual with shadow properties, you should refer to them by *name* using the `string` overloads of the corresponding fluent API.

In your case:

```
entity.HasAlternateKey("HeaderId", "Version", "StartDate");
entity.HasOne(e => e.Header).WithMany().HasForeignKey("HeaderId");
```